# How to Uninstall Ubuntu Linux from Secondary Drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, hard-drive

this question might seem pretty basic and straightforward but I wanted to make I do it properly without data loss.

I have two drives. My primary being windows 8. My secondary is partitioned with one part being Ubuntu and the other partion being room for storing my back up files, important files.

So my question is how do I remove the partition and uninstall Ubuntu from my secondary? I'd also like the space freed up from the process to go back and combine to one partition so I have more storage space for my back up files.

As you can see I gave ubuntu way to much space.
C drive is windows 8. E Drive is my storage drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's ironic that you're asking about this in an Ubuntu forum.

You can delete and expand partitions right from the disk management screen you're at.

Simply delete that 634G partition, then click on the E: partition, and choose "extend volume". Once you delete the parition, everything on it will disappear. There's nothing to uninstall.

Comment: I deleted the 634 GB volume. Clicked on the E: partition and then I chose 'Extend volume' and this message appears. "The operation you selected will convert the selected disk to dynamic disk. if you convert the disk to dynamic, you will not be able to start installed operating system from any volume on the disk (except the current boot volume). are you sure you want to continue?"

Comment: If you're not comfortable doing that, try a 3rd party utility, such as [Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), which is free. It should just be able to expand the partition without having to convert the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleting the partition and extending the other partition should do the trick. Just be careful about that 9.7GB partition near the beginning of that disk. If you are booting with GRUB (the Ubuntu boot manager) and it's installed on that partition (although large for a boot partition) you may not be able to boot into Windows. You would then need to run start up repair to replace your MBR and boot sector.
If Windows was installed after Ubuntu, and it boots right into windows you may not have to worry about it.